# Imagemagick destination name changes when squaring an image

Tags: imagemagick

I wrote a script to go through a source directory, resize the image to a square and save the results to a destination directory.  It works fine except the name changes when saved in the destination directory.

Example:
source name: 111010xx1.jpg
stored in destination as: *-1.jpg

Here is the script:

```
for file in *.jpg; do
    convert -background white -gravity center images/source/$file -resize 400x400 -extent 400x400 images/available/$file;
done
```

Any ideas as to why the name change?

Thanks

Comment: Did you attempt to use `-crop` operator before `-extent`?

Comment: The middle line should be `convert -background white -gravity center "$file" -resize ... -extent ... images/available/"$file"`

Comment: Filenames beginning with digits are sometimes problematic.